# SSH forwarding using WSL2 and VS code containers on Windows

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Ubuntu running under WSL2 on Windows. Inside Ubuntu I have cloned my repository, which is set up to run docker. When I run `docker-compose up` inside the project, it successfully starts, and I can open the container from VS code on Windows.

The issue arises when I try to use any git feature from inside VS code. I just get a `permission denied (publickey)`. If I open the terminal inside VS code (which is connected to the container), I get the same error when running `git pull`.

If I run `docker-compose run web bash` from the Ubuntu terminal, I can successfully run `git pull`. So the agent is forwarded to the container, it just doesn't work from VS Code.

Is there some setup I'm missing?

Answer (score 6):

To get VS Code to use your SSH keys from your WSL2 instance inside a Docker container running on the WSL2 backend, you need to tell WSL2 to **create an ssh-agent at startup**, and **add your ssh key to the agent**. When VS Code attaches to a container running on the WSL2 backend, it will automatically pick up the running ssh-agent, and allow you to authenticate with your WSL2 SSH keys inside your container.

For either of the methods, you will need `socat` installed in WSL2

```
sudo apt install socat
```

### Method 1 - Manual Bash Script

To tell your WSL2 distro to start it's ssh-agent on boot, you will need to add these lines to your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zprofile (for Zsh) so ssh-agent starts when WSL2 starts:

```bash
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
   # Check for a currently running instance of the agent
   RUNNING_AGENT="`ps -ax | grep 'ssh-agent -s' | grep -v grep | wc -l | tr -d '[:space:]'`"
   if [ "$RUNNING_AGENT" = "0" ]; then
        # Launch a new instance of the agent
        ssh-agent -s &> $HOME/.ssh/ssh-agent
   fi
   eval `cat $HOME/.ssh/ssh-agent`
fi

# also add your key to this ssh-agent session
# 
# When run without arguments, it adds the files ~/.ssh/id_rsa, ~/.ssh/id_dsa, 
# ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk, ~/.ssh/id_ed25519, and ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk. 
# Source: https://man.cx/ssh-add
ssh-add 

# if you had to create ~/.bash_profile, these lines may also be needed
# to load your ~/.bashrc config
#
# test and run the .bashrc file if it exists (this is the default on Ubuntu for WSL2) 
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

### Method 2 - Keychain

[Keychain](https://www.funtoo.org/Keychain) basically does the same as above, but with one easy command. It is not installed by default so you will have to install it using your distro's package manager or from source.

```
sudo apt install keychain
```

Once keychain is installed, add the following to your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zprofile`:

```
# keychain will start the ssh agent and add the keys, or reuse the ssh agent
# if it is already running
eval `keychain --eval --agents ssh id_rsa`

# ...
```

You can also use keychain to set up your GPG keys, if any.

If `~/.bash profile` did not already exist, (which it does not for a default install of Ubuntu on WSL2), then you will need to add the following lines to the end of your `~/.bash_profile` so that `~/.bashrc` is properly sourced when using bash.

```
# run the .bashrc file if it exists (this is the default on WSL2 if this does not already exist)
# these lines may already exist if .bash_profile already exists
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

### References

https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/sharing-git-credentials#_using-ssh-keys

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2925#issuecomment-652558889